# Cómo crear una base de datos MySQL con comandos SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Me gustaría saber cómo crear una base de datos en MySQL utilizando comandos SQL, que mi puedo correr en MySQL Workbench, o en phpMyAdmin o cualquier otro software.

¿Qué comandos SQL necesarios para crear una base de datos y sus tablas?

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer la pregunta un poco más específica? Tal y como está ahora se podría responder con la sintaxis para crear bases de datos y tablas, pero sería algo bastante general y no sé si te serviría

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro servir a sí! Sí me mostraría cómo crear una base de datos en MySQL y cuáles son los principales comandos para crear una base de datos!

Comment: No entiendo porque se votó por cerrar esta pregunta, desde mi punto de vista no tiene nada de malo y no es para nada amplia, de echo la respondieron sin problemas

Answer (score 5):

Tanto para crear una base de datos como una tabla, vas a necesitar el comando `CREATE`. Lo que va a cambiar son los parámetros que vienen después.

Para crear una base de datos la sintáxis básica sería ([documentación](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html)):

```
CREATE DATABASE [nombre-de-la-base-de-datos];
```

> Nota: la sintaxis real es más complicada, he intentado ajustarme a lo más básico posible

Donde `[nombre-de-la-base-de-datos]` es el nombre que quieres ponerle a la base de datos (no hacen falta comillas). Por ejemplo, si quieres que se llame mibd, serías así:

```
CREATE DATABASE mibd;
```

---

Crear una tabla es algo más complicado porque necesitas saber cosas como qué columnas vas a necesitar, qué tipo tendrán, qué restricciones (*constraints*) tendrán los campos, qué relación habrá entre la tabla y otras tablas, etc.

La sintaxis básica para crear una tabla es la siguiente ([documentación](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)):

```
CREATE TABLE [nombre-de-la-tabla] (
   [nombre-de-columna] [tipo-de-la-columna] [restricción-de-la-columna],
   [nombre-de-columna] [tipo-de-la-columna] [restricción-de-la-columna],
   ...

)
```

> Nota: la sintaxis real es más complicada, he intentado ajustarme a lo más básico posible

Donde:

- `[nombre-de-la-tabla]` es el nombre de la tabla que quieres crear
- `[nombre-de-la-columna]` es el nombre de la columna en la tabla, no puede haber dos iguales
- `[tipo-de-la-columna]` es el tipo que tendrá esa columna: INT, VARCHAR(tamaño), DATE...
- `[restricción-de-la-columna]` es opcional y serían las restricciones que puede tener esa columna: NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY...

Por ejemplo, para crear una tabla de personas que tenga 3 columnas: id, nombre y fecha de nacimiento, el código para crear la tabla sería algo como esto:

```
CREATE TABLE persona (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(100),
    fecha_nac DATE
)
```

---

Pero lo dicho, la sintaxis real es mucho más complicada que todo eso y podrías tener ejemplos mucho más complejos que los que he puesto.

Comment: muí gracias por tu respuesta!